# Disconnect from server if any exception is raised inside a class in Python

Tags: python, class, exception

I'm running an application made with PyQt that basically reads information from an OPC server and updates a plot every time new data comes in.

I would like to be able to safely disconnect from the OPC server every time the application is closed. This includes the user manually closing the window *and* any runtime error that might occur. It would be something like this:

```
from opcua import Client
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtWidgets

class ApplicationWindow_Realtime(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):      
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ApplicationWindow_Realtime, self).__init__(parent)
        self.opc_url = 'opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:53530/UA/Sim'
        self.opc_initialize()

        ## DO STUFF

    ## Connect to OPC
    def opc_initialize(self):
        self.client = Client(self.opc_url)
        self.client.connect()

    ## OTHER METHODS

    # Disconnect if window is closed
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.client.disconnect()
```

I want to know if there is some way to call `self.client.disconnect()` if any error occurs in runtime when running the application. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420464/python-catch-exceptions-inside-a-class) but the accepted answer starts with "Warning: if you want something like this, it's likely you don't... but if you really want to...", so I'm not sure if this is the right way to tackle the problem.

Comment: You should probably separate the code that implements your interface from the code that executes your application logic. Instead of connecting to the client from within `__init__`, initialize the connection in the same place that you create the window.

Comment: @chepner I'm creating the window from another window (its parent). Is it possible then to treat from the original window exceptions that were raised in the child window?

Comment: Exceptions percolate up the run-time call stack; where methods are defined isn't really important.

Comment: @chepner But how can I catch any exception that has been raised? I only know of the `try ... except...` way. Is this the way to go, with the child creation in the `try` block only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something similar to the answer you linked but I would define it within the class itself.

```
from functools import wraps

def _emergency_disconnect(the_func):
    @wraps(the_func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        output = None
        try:
            output = the_func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            #args[0] will always be self
            args[0].client.disconnect()
        if output != None:
            return output
    return wrapper
```

Then you can decorate your functions with it

```
@_emergency_disconnect
def myFunction(myArg):
    pass
```

This will cause self.client.disconnect() to be called whenever a method call results in an error.